# Current name for h1 instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, nosql

Does anybody know what is the current equivalent to AWS h1 instances? I think it's the i type but I'm not really sure if it's that or the r type. 
Anyway, my purpose is running a cassandra cluster on these servers, currently running on 6 r3.2xlarge servers.

Any further advice to whether this is the best server for this type of operation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Yaron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The I2 family [are indeed](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) the I/O optimised successors to the H1 family. AWS themselves recommend them for NoSQL database operations.

Although a little out of date now [Datastax themselves recommend](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/ec2-series-doc) as a progression in price and performance: M series, C series, and finally the I series.

Comment: Thanks, gave me all the info I need.